# Add case statement in where Clause with Date Between

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add cases in where clause with Date between, but getting  syntax error.

i had showing syntax error in *AND*, *hh* etc on below code

```
select * from my_under mu
    where mu.modified_date between
        CASE 
            WHEN @lastRunTime IS NOT NULL 
                THEN @lastRunTime *AND*  DATEADD(hh,-@timeInterval,DATEADD(Mi,1,@lastRunTime))
            *ELSE* 
                DATEADD(*hh*,-@timeInterval,DATEADD(*Mi*,1,GETDATE())) AND DATEADD(*hh*,-@timeInterval,GETDATE()) 
        END
```

Please let me know whats wrong in syntax

Comment: Use AND/OR instead of case,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below query (AND/OR) logic to achieve your expectation, since it is easy instead of using `CASE` statement.

Based on the `@lastRunTime` value (NULL/NOT NULL), any one of the where condition will work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_under mu
WHERE (@lastRunTime IS NOT NULL 
       AND (mu.modified_date BETWEEN @lastRunTime AND DATEADD(hh, -@timeInterval, DATEADD(Mi, 1, @lastRunTime)))
      )
    OR
      (@lastRunTime IS NULL 
       AND (mu.modified_date BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, -@timeInterval, DATEADD(Mi, 1, GETDATE())) AND DATEADD(hh, -@timeInterval, GETDATE()))
      )
```

Comment: @user3297547 Could you confirm the above answer is works? If not we can add/alter for the correct solution.